# AssertionFailedError on junit test with Robotium

Tags: java, android, exception, junit

I keep getting the following exception on every test and I can't figure out why.  Hoping someone has some insight.

```
 ----- begin exception -----
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 
Activity named mainActivity can not be returned to
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ActivityUtils.goBackToActivity(ActivityUtils.java:185)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.goBackToActivity(Solo.java:1864)
at com.package.test.AppointmentSettingTestBase.tearDown(AppointmentSettingTestBase.java:64)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:130)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:525)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1547)
```

----- end exception -----

Answer (score 1):

You have write the correct name of the Activity you want to go back to. I think the name of your activity is MainActivity and not mainActivity.